# Pointer in struct is placed on two struct members

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am trying to implement a ring buffer with C. I am declaring a struct ring_buffer with some parameters, an pointer array to the ring_buffer elements and a callback function (pointer) to free the buffer elements.

```
struct ring_buffer
{
    size_t size, count, head;
    void **elems;
    void (*free_callback)(void *p);
};
typedef struct ring_buffer ring_buffer;
```

In Addition to that i got an init function to create a new instance of the struct.

```
ring_buffer *init_buffer(const size_t n, void (*f)(void *p))
{
    ring_buffer *buffer = NULL;
    size_t count = 0, head = 0;
    void **elems = NULL;

    if(n <= 0 || f == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    buffer = malloc(sizeof(buffer));
    elems = (void**)malloc(n * sizeof(void*));

    *buffer = (ring_buffer){.size = n, .count = count, .head = head, .elems = elems, .free_callback = f};

    return buffer;
}
```

Now i got the following problem:
After calling the init_buffer function and creating the new struct the pointer of the callback function is placed on the free_callback member of the struct and the first index of the elems array too! Which means 
`free_callback == elems[0]`.

I am pretty confused by that as i am allocating enough space for the whole array and the struct as well so why is the free_callback pointer overlapping with the 1st index of the array.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
buffer = malloc(sizeof(buffer));
```

you allocate storage with size of pointer, not ring buffer.
please rewrite:

```
buffer = malloc(sizeof(ring_buffer))
```